# form action call button

Tags: javascript, forms, jquery-ui

In a form, i have a button and an image... when i click on image, form action is called, that work... but when i click on the button action is not called.
Is there a specific thing to do for a button?

js

```
$('#formUser').submit(function() {
  $(this).attr("action", "/secure/downloaduserinfo/" + reportName);
});


$('#formUser').submit(function() {
  $(this).attr("action", "/secure/deleteuser/" + reportName);
});
```

web part

```
<button type="button" id="deleteUserButton${statusReport.count}"></button>

<input id="downloadUserButton${statusReport.count}" type="image"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

`type="button"` elements are not submit buttons, they exist solely to run client side code.

If you want to submit the form, use `type="submit"` (or don't specify a type attribute at all, submit is the default).

---

That said, I'd avoid the dependancy on JavaScript. Give the buttons and name and a value and use that *on the server* to determine if you want to download or delete.

Answer (score 1):

The input of type "image" is similar to "submit", it does submit your form, that's why your submit handler is working. While the input of type "button" does not submit the form, it just looks like a button.

Comment: the problem is: when i click on the delete button, this one call a dialog... it display the dialog and close directly.... so don't think i can use submit type

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 submit listeners for the same element so every time the `#formUser` is submitted it uses the first submit listener it finds.

You can use the onclick listener and tie it to the specific element being clicked.

I'm not sure how the templating system it looks like you're using is tied in but I'd use a class instead of the id.

```
<button type="button" class="delete-user-button" id="deleteUserButton99">Delete</button>
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="download-user-button" id="downloadUserButton99"/>



<script>
    $('.delete-user-button').click(function() {
      // store object that was clicked
      var obj = $(this);

      // set that objects action attribute
      obj.attr("action", "/secure/deleteuser/" + obj.attr('id'));

      // show the action attribute's value
      alert(obj.attr('action'));
    });


    $('.download-user-button').click(function() {
      // store object that was clicked
      var obj = $(this);

      // set that objects action attribute
      obj.attr("action", "/secure/downloaduserinfo/" + obj.attr('id'));

      // show the action attribute's value
      alert(obj.attr('action'));
    });
    </script>
```

Here's a fiddle that demonstrates manipulating the object by the click listener: http://jsfiddle.net/chapmanc/HHfQT/2/